# Centering dynamic text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have song titles received from my Icecast server and are always changing according to the playlist.

Obviously some titles are longer then the others and vise versa.

I'm trying to center the text in that box so it would always fit in the middle, no matter the title length.

How can i achieve that?

- [The player](http://radio.tranceil.co.il)

The Div CSS:

```
.now_playing div {
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:24px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    right: 36px;
}
```

The Anchor CSS:

```
.now_playing a {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
   position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;

}
```

Comment: Just remove position: absolute from the a tag.

Comment: have you tried .now_playing a { margin: 0 auto; } instead of left : 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this rule

```
.now_playing a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and remove `padding-left: 100px;` from `.now_playing div` selector.

Comment: But then it spans over the full width, I think he just wants the text to be clickable, i.e. the a tag centered in the div?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that a song title span full width. so with short title songs, users will be easily switch between songs.

Comment: Your solution worked...i was trying to center the text as the song title changes, but it was too long...using your rules, and lowering the font size seems to fix the issue, ill accept in 5 minuetes

Answer (score 1):

For text use:

```
text-align:center;
```

For divs use:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTQqK/)

EDIT: added 0px to margin. properly clearing all margins before centering

Comment: Shouldn't it be margin: 0 auto;?